# CXF's readEntity() got "Entity is not available"

Tags: cxf

I am working on a piece of code that uses `CXF` (3.1.2)

I am seeing this error intermittently:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Entity is not available
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.checkEntityIsClosed(ResponseImpl.java:481)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.doReadEntity(ResponseImpl.java:333)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.readEntity(ResponseImpl.java:320)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.readEntity(ResponseImpl.java:310)
```

To improve performance, the `Response` objects are held through a Google Guava `LoadingCache` (`com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache`).  It seems like I would get this error after an object has been in the cache for a few minutes.  Could the `Response` object because invalid 
after a few minutes?

```
private static LoadingCache<String, Response> cachedLdapRespMap
    = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .maximumSize(Constants.LDAP_RESP_CACHE_SIZE)
        .expireAfterWrite(Constants.LDAP_RESP_CACHE_KEEP_ALIVE_MINUTE
                            , TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build(
                new CacheLoader<String, Response>() {

                    @Override
                    public Response load(String uid)
                            throws Exception {
                        Response res = makeLdapRequest(uid);
                        return res;
                    }

                }
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am answer the question myself)

The problem was that I have concurrent processes that attempted to `readEntity()`, the first process consumed the input stream (or may have even closed the stream), and the second process would either get thrown an `IllegalStateException` or got an empty message.  Here is what the [JavaDoc of `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#getEntity--) (which `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl` extends) says:

> **Throws:**
>
> IllegalStateException - if the entity is not backed by an
>   input stream, the response has been closed already, or if the entity
>   input stream has been fully consumed already and has not been buffered
>   prior consuming.

So to fix the problem, I changed my design to cache not the `Response` object but rather the string message that is the result of the `readEntity()` call.  The call would be done exactly once when the response comes back:

```
Response resp ...
String respStr = resp.readEntity(String.class);
```

and the problem is solved.